# access css class properties in selenium

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I have a HTML `<div>` element and wish to check if it is left aligned using Selenium. However the `float:left` CSS property is defined in a CSS class.

Is there any way in which I can access the CSS class attributes through Selenium? Alternately is there any other way to get this value?

```
<div class="myclass">
...
</div>
```

In sample.css

```
.myclass{
   float:left;
}
```

I was trying to use `getEval()` - `this.page().findElement("foo")` to find out a way to get CSS class attributes.

Answer (score 1):

With webdriver you can use css selektors:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".myclass"));
String float = element.getCssValue("float");
```

See [Javadoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) of WebElement

**Updated Answer!**

Comment: yes, i can do that the way you have mentioned. However, I wish to check (through Selenium) that this <div> element is left aligned. So basically, I need a way to access the 'float:left' CSS property, which is defined in CSS Class 'myclass', through Selenium.

Comment: seems a good solution, but we are not using webdriver, so cannot use this solution. i am trying to use getElementPositionLeft and providing a range to detect left aligned. Not a great solution, but using it nevertheless.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using WebDriver?  `findelement()` is part of the WebDriver API, not the Selenium RC API.