# Access a class attribute that appears when check box is selected in Ruby with Selenium

Tags: html, css, ruby, xpath, selenium

I have a tag that looks like the following:

```
<ul id="genres-bar" >
```

When a user selects the "Romance" check box the background with change and the tag turns into:

```
<ul id="genres-bar" class=" romance">
```

How do I verify/ access this attribute? Over all I want to verify that the color change occurred.

I notice this css snippet appears when the check box is clicked:

```
#movies.gen-romance .m-gen-R {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

And it disappears when not checked.

I am new to html, css, xpaths, etc. and I may just be having trouble finding similar questions but my research so far hasn't given me an answer I can understand.

This answer was helpful but is in java. I can't figure out how to apply it to my problem but it seems so similar:

[access css class properties in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826392/access-css-class-properties-in-selenium)

And this is my attempt to locate the element so far:

```
verify {@driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="genres-bar" @class=" romance"]')}
```

Comment: what you want to check? *How do I verify/ access this attribute?* what attr you want to access/

Comment: When I select the check box the: class=" romance" appears and so does the css snippet. I guess as I wrote the question I assumed these things are related and that by accessing class =" romance" I could verify the element changed color.

Comment: Check my answer,hope that will help you.

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Comment: Had to walk away from it last night, hopped on it today and got it right. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the below two part might help you. Although i am not clear about your needs:

[`css_value(prop)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#css_value-instance_method) and [`attribute(name)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#attribute-instance_method) will be helpful. in your case.

```
@driver.find_element(:css, '#genres-bar').css_value('background-color')
# => '#FF0000'
@driver.find_element(:css, '#genres-bar').attribute('class')
# => " romance"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you do something like this

```
verify {@driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="genres-bar"][@class=" romance"]')}
```

or

```
verify {@driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="genres-bar" and @class=" romance"]')}
```

You had nearly got the xpath right.